# Calling a function that is defined in a fetch from elsewhere outside of the fetch

Tags: javascript, function, fetch

I'm currently having issues figuring out how to call a function that is defined inside an API Fetch responce function. I currently have an API fetch going out to the github API to get a repository tree. It comes back as a JSON file and my code does all of its stuff. The issue is that I have a function that is defined in the fetch (that I would like to call outside of the fetch, so I dont have to "re-fetch" each time), and I cant call it outside of the fetch (its sorta like a function inside a function).

I've looked around online and asked around and I cant seem to find any answers. I'm fairly new to JS (yes I know my code is messy).

Here is a snippet of my current code:

```js
fetch(api_TreeURL)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(json) {
        function GetSortOrder(prop) {    
            return function(a, b) {    
                if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {    
                    return 1;    
                } else if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {    
                    return -1;    
                }    
                return 0;    
            }    
        }    

        function DELTA_location(currrentlLocation) {
            var parentlocation = document.getElementById("delta");
            var dirLocation = document.createElement("div")
            var dirLocationText = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","a")
            var lastChar = currrentlLocation.substr(-1);
            
            parentlocation.append(dirLocation)
            dirLocation.append(dirLocationText)
            dirLocation.setAttribute("class","delta-location")
        
            if (lastChar != '/') {
                currrentlLocation = currrentlLocation + '/';
            }
        
            dirLocationText.innerHTML = currrentlLocation
        }
    }).catch(function(ex) {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex)
})
```

If I try and call `DELTA_location("")` from anywhere outside of the fetch, eg;

```js
fetch(api_TreeURL)
    "...the code..."
})

DELTA_location("test")
```

It will return the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: DELTA_fetch is not defined`
Same if I call it from a button in the HTML file.

If you would like to view all of the code, vist the [Github](https://github.com/TitusStudiosMediaGroup/DELTA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is use a reference to the function eg :
Outside the fetch code you write

```
let DELTA_location_ref = (a) => console.warn('Function not fetched yet');
```

then inside the fetch code you overwrite this variable as :

```
DELTA_location_ref = (currrentlLocation) =>  {
        var parentlocation = document.getElementById("delta");
        var dirLocation = document.createElement("div")
        var dirLocationText = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","a")
        var lastChar = currrentlLocation.substr(-1);
        
        parentlocation.append(dirLocation)
        dirLocation.append(dirLocationText)
        dirLocation.setAttribute("class","delta-location")
    
        if (lastChar != '/') {
            currrentlLocation = currrentlLocation + '/';
        }
    
        dirLocationText.innerHTML = currrentlLocation
    }
```

using closures (arrow functions) is important here because you want to have access to the context of the fetch when called from outside

Note that you delta location function does not use the return of the fetch (the json variable) so i don't know why you define it there

Comment: Awesome dude! This worked like gold. However my HTML generation doesnt work if I call it from outside, but works if I call it inside the fetch, still working that one out. And yes that example code I put up was just an example, there is alot more functions in there that I left out. (Edit fixed the HTML Issue, was clearing the div after adding the new HTML oops!!) Cheers dude!